# Как программно снять выбор с <material-radio> в группе?

Tags: angular, dart

Как программно снять выбор с  в группе? То есть сначала пользователь выбирает один радио, после этого жмет кнопку перехода ДАЛЕЕ и нужно в той же форме снять все выборы.

Вот код компонента:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: [
    MaterialRadioComponent,
    MaterialRadioGroupComponent,
    MaterialButtonComponent,
    NgFor,
    NgIf,
    NgModel,
    ViewChild,
    ViewChildren,
    ContentChildren
    ],
  providers: [materialProviders]
)
class AppComponent {
  final List<String> list_P = [
    'Вовлеченный', 'Прямолинейный', 'Делающий', 'Отдающий себе отчет', 'Результативный', 
    'Упорный', 'Активный', 'Прагматичный', 'Побеждающий', 'Рациональный', 'Деловой', 'Реалистичный'
  ];
  final List<String> list_A = [
    'Сомневающийся', 'Анализирующий', 'Созерцающий', 'Оценивающий', 'Логичный', 'Консервативный', 
    'Наблюдающий', 'Размышляющий', 'Точный', 'Сдержанный', 'Аккуратный', 'Осторожный'
  ];
  final List<String> list_E = [
    'Яркий', 'Харизматичный', 'Провоцирующий', 'Идущий на риск', 'Задающий вопросы', 'Радикальный', 
    'Абстрактный', 'Смотрящий в будущее', 'Концептуальный', 'Генерирующий идеи', 'Творческий', 'Мечтающий'
  ];
  final List<String> list_I = [
    'Отзывчивый', 'Чувствующий', 'Сопереживающий', 'Благожелательный', 'Интуитивный', 'Общительный', 
    'Взаимодействующий', 'Теплый', 'Стремящийся к консенсусу', 'Осведомленный', 'Приятный', 'Объединяющий'
  ];

  int counter=0;

  increment() {
    if(counter<11){
    counter++;
    uncheckAll();
    }
  }

  decrement() {
    if(counter!=0){
      counter--;
    }
  }

  String get skill_P => list_P[counter];
  String get skill_A => list_A[counter];
  String get skill_E => list_E[counter];
  String get skill_I => list_I[counter];

  final scillScore = [1, 2, 3, 4]; //задаем значения для оценок скилла
  int selected_P = 0; // объявляем начальные значения оценок скиллов
  int selected_A = 0;
  int selected_E = 0;
  int selected_I = 0;

  int get value_P => selected_P; // получаем значения выбранных оценок для каждого скилла
  int get value_A => selected_A;
  int get value_E => selected_E;
  int get value_I => selected_I;

  String get result => (value_P+value_A+value_E+value_I).toString(); // выводим сумму оценок

  @ViewChildren(MaterialRadioGroupComponent)
  List<MaterialRadioGroupComponent> groups;

  void uncheckAll() {
    for(MaterialRadioGroupComponent child in groups){
      print(child.selected);
    }
    }
  }
```

Также приведу код шаблона:

```
<h1>Узнайте свою формулу PAEI - какой Вы руководитель?</h1>
<p>Перед Вами 10 блоков, содержащие по 4 качества личности.
    Присвойте каждому качеству от 1-го до 4-ех баллов в зависимости от того,
    насколько оно подходит именно вам. Общая сумма баллов одного блока
    должна быть равна 10.</p>
<hr>
<div>
    <div class="skillrow">{{skill_P}}</div>
    <div class="radiorow">
        <material-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected_P">
            <material-radio *ngFor="let item of scillScore" [value]="item">
                {{ item }}
            </material-radio>
        </material-radio-group>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="skillrow">{{skill_A}}</div>
    <div class="radiorow">
        <material-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected_A">
            <material-radio *ngFor="let item of scillScore" [value]="item">
                {{ item }}
            </material-radio>
        </material-radio-group>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="skillrow">{{skill_E}}</div>
    <div class="radiorow">
        <material-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected_E">
            <material-radio *ngFor="let item of scillScore" [value]="item">
                {{ item }}
            </material-radio>
        </material-radio-group>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="skillrow">{{skill_I}}</div>
    <div class="radiorow">
        <material-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected_I">
            <material-radio *ngFor="let item of scillScore" [value]="item">
                {{ item }}
            </material-radio>
        </material-radio-group>
    </div>
</div>
<p *ngIf="value_P!=null">Оценочка: {{result}}</p>
<p *ngIf="value_P==null">Ничего не выбрано, лузер!</p>
<hr>
<div class="navigation">
    <material-button class="button" (click)="decrement">Назад</material-button>
    <material-button class="button" (click)="increment">Далее</material-button>
</div>
```

В функции uncheckAll() я смог получить экземпляр объекта MaterialRadioGroupComponent. Дальше пробую из этого экземпляра получить доступ к списку элементов MaterialRadioComponent через свойство radioComponents, но IDE ругается, что "The getter 'radioComponents' isn't defined for the class 'MaterialRadioGroupComponent'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно получить доступ к инстансу компонента `material-radio-group` внутри шаблона. Сделать это можно с помощью `@ViewChild`:

```
class RadioScreenComponent {
    @ViewChild(MaterialRadioGroupComponent)
    MaterialRadioGroupComponent group = null;
}
```

У экземпляра этого класса есть сеттер `selected`:

```
set selected(dynamic selectedValue)
```

То есть вам нужно этому свойству просто присвоить значение `null`:

```
class RadioScreenComponent {
    @ViewChild(MaterialRadioGroupComponent)
    MaterialRadioGroupComponent group = null;

    void uncheckAllRadioButtons() {
        group.selected = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пока не получается, но общая идея понятна. Я должен получить доступ к material-radio-group из РОДИТЕЛЬСКОГО компонента, используя @ViewChild. Получив этот доступ, программно снимаю с них выбор

Comment: да, идея такая, в js'e это работает (я проверил), к сожалению не работал с дартом и не могу проверить :(

Comment: у меня в цикле подчеркивает radioComponents, пишет The getter 'radioComponents' isn't defined for the class 'MaterialRadioGroupComponent'.dart(undefined_getter)

Comment: То есть нужно сделать геттер, пока не понял - как. Просто пока времени нет подумать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87984/discussion-between--and-overthesanity).

Comment: Изменил код в вопросе, чтобы все было в одном компоненте и шаблоне

Comment: так вы попробовали через сеттер `selected`? `void uncheckAll() { group.selected = null }`

Comment: супер, заработало))